# Chat Resizifizer

Tags: script, chat

Are you you annoyed when you are typing a long chat message, but the textbox is so short? Worry no more! This userscript makes it possible to resize the entire bottom part of the chat page (a.k.a. `#input-area`). Better yet, the textbox (`#input`) resizes with it:

> [image]

### Installation

With Greasemonkey:

- Go to https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/raw/master/customizations/ChatInputResizifizer.user.js.
- Click <kbd>Install</kbd>.

For installation on other browsers, see [the [script] tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

Lisenced under [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/).

### Code

Hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/blob/master/customizations/ChatInputResizifizer.user.js.

### Bugs

Report bugs on either this page or [on GitHub](https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/issues/new).

Currently known bugs include:

- It can cover up starred messages.
- `#input` can be vertically resized independently of `#input-area`.